# OpenMP Parallelization of sequential functions that are not within a for loop

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp

`GlobalDefines.h` has the following `#defined`

```
#define FOO_1 true//true if function void foo1() should run, false otherwise
#define FOO_2 false//true if function void foo2() should run, false otherwise
```

Within `src.cpp`, these are used thus:

```
#include GlobalDefines.h

class BigClassX{
    std::vector<int>...;
    ....
};

BigClassX ObjX;

int main(){

    #if FOO_1
       foo1(objX);
    #if FOO_2
       foo2(objX);

}
```

`foo1` (likewise `foo2`) takes in its argument by reference thus:

`void foo1(class BigClassX& objX){}`

I would like to parallelize `foo1` and `foo2` even though they are not in a `for` loop.

My attempt was the following and it seems a bit roundabout in that I explicitly have to introduce a `for` loop:

```
#pragma omp parallel for
for(int i = 1; i <= 2; i++)
    foox(i, objX);
```

Now, `foox` is thus:

```
void foox(int indicator, class BigClassX& objX){
    if(FOO_1 && indicator == 1)
        foo1(objX);
    if(FOO_2 && indicator == 2)
        foo2(objX);
}
```

Is there any other way to parallelize this within OpenMP? My concerns with the above method are:

(1)Is there any performance hit with passing around big object `objX` by reference across OpenMP `parallel for` construct? Since it is a big object, I anyways pass it by reference, but is there anything in particular I should be worried about when placing that within an OpenMP `parallel for` construct?

(2)As indicated above, it seems a bit round about since I am having to introduce a new function `foox` and within `foox` I have to check which function to call based on the `indicator`.

Comment: Your question is rather general. I provided a general answer. I fear that it may possibly be too general for you to be useful. If this doesn't fully help you,  would have been better if you, please post a follow-up question in which you clearly describe the actual use case in form of a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### 1. Don't abuse the preprocessor like this.

Just don't - unless it is absolutely unavoidable. Besides your example is missing `#endif`. You **will** burn yourself or others with this, you **will** suffer. Instead of use `if constexpr` - or just a regular if on a `const` or `constexpr`. This is fine.

#### 2. This is a use case for OpenMP sections

Your code looks like

```
#pragma omp parallel sections
{
    #pragma omp section
    {
        foo1(objX);
    }
    #pragma omp section
    {
        foo2(objX);
    }
}
```

#### 3. Avoid race conditions

In general, this object is *shared* between the sections and the same reference is passed to `foo1` and `foo2`. Working on shared objects in parallel is dangerous. You must avoid any access to the same *leaf* elements (individual values) within `objX` unless **all** sections **only read**.

Depending on your specific case you can use `atomic` operations or `critical` sections to protect against race conditions.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer on preprocessor. I will look into constexpr. The reason why I use #defines is that my project is not very big, so recompiling is not that difficult/time consuming. Besides, the IDE displays differently between active and inactive subsections of the code when enclosed within #if's